# Cannot create an outlet on swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create an outlet but xcode doesn't let me, I press ctrl+drag as always.

Here a screenshot of the viewcontroller and `conversationVC.swift`:

[image]

btw in the top right when I write the class as `conversationVC.swift` it always delete itself and stays empty,

please share your knowledge.

Comment: Check if you correctly set the class of the `UIViewController` to `conversationVC`. Also, you are trying to link it between line 14 & 19, right?

Comment: In storyboard or XIB make sure you select the scene from the left side and write your Controller name in Class field, also **Target membership** your app

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19081533/10256238), need to click on yellow button and then to set the class name